# Request exceeded the limit of 10

Tags: .htaccess, regex

My logs are FULL of

`[Tue Jan 11 10:20:45 2011] [error] [client 99.162.115.123] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://www.domain.com/vehicles/Chevrolet/Uplander/2006`

The problem is when I enable `LogLevel debug` we get HUGE error logs because all of our traffic is SSL.  From what I can tell the file doesn't record these errors anymore, either that or it's so buried in SSL logs that I just can't find them.

Here's my .htaccess

```
Options -indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^battery/([^/]+)$ /browser/product?sku=BATTERY+$1&type=battery
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/product([0-9]+)$ /browser/index.php?make=$1&model=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /browser/product.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&id=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /store/product/list.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /vehicle/make/model/year/list.php?make=$1&model=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)$ /vehicle/make/model/list.php?make=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Enable logging of rewrite rules via `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`.  This should help you track down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: never ever test in production environment things like this. Install a test server and do one HTTP request there and then look the log. You should be easily able to identify stuff specific to this request.

This debug data is very helpful when solving problems regarding mod_rewrite resolution loops. Basically, it logs every step it is doing and prints the resolution.

```
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /store/product/list.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

This is most likely the rule you want for this case. Instead of this getting effect, the parsing stops to second rule:

```
RewriteRule ^battery/([^/]+)$ /browser/product?sku=BATTERY+$1&type=battery
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/product([0-9]+)$ /browser/index.php?make=$1&model=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

Since it has [L], last entry. The substitution will stop there. RewriteRules doesn’t care if the URL doesn’t match.

Instead use [RewriteConds](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to do the matching. If they match, the rule will be used, and if not, execution will continue after the rule.

So something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /store/product/list.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

You could also use params defined in RewriteCond, if you want cleaner rules, with %1.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try it without this line ?

> RewriteRule
>   ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/product([0-9]+)$
>   /browser/index.php?make=$1&model=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}
>   [L,NC]

Maybe it get confused with the extra parenthesis in product (it's just a guess)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your rewriting rules, the one that match your URL is :

```
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /store/product/list.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

That is rewitten as:

```
/store/product/list.php?make=Chevrolet&model=Uplander&year=2006&
```

As larsks and others pointed out, at this point, you should:

> Enable logging of rewrite rules via
>   RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel. This
>   should help you track down the
>   problem. – larsks Jan 11 at 16:50

This way you will see what is happening, and you can then post here the logs to have further help.

Then be aware that mod_rewrite code is executed for each and every HTTP request that accesses a file in or below the directory where the code resides, so this could be the root of your problem.

You can use the following code, which tests if the url does not end in .php and if it doesn't, it will skip the next 6 RewriteRules.

```
RewriteRule !\.php$ - [S=6]
RewriteRule ^battery/([^/]+)$ /browser/product?sku=BATTERY+$1&type=battery
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/product([0-9]+)$ /browser/index.php?make=$1&model=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]  
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /browser/product.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&id=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /store/product/list.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /vehicle/make/model/year/list.php?make=$1&model=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vehicles/([^/]+)$ /vehicle/make/model/list.php?make=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

Hope it helps